# Isolate y in this equation: $y ^ 2 + y = x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a simple homework thing for my college. Is there a way to isolate $y$ in this case:
$$
y ^ 2 + y = x
$$
I tried everything and I can't solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Quadratic formula or completing the square would be a couple of techniques I'd suggest as either may work.

Comment: try this $y^2 + y = (y+   1/2)^2   -  1/4$

Comment: @LeandroTavares That doesn't make sense to me. How did you arrive to that formula? Sorry if I am a beginner, still learning math at college.

Comment: @JBKing Tried them, doesn't work.

Comment: @Pacha You really should tell us why it did not work because it is impossible for us to guess what you did wrong.

Comment: Pacha: @LeandroTavares' method is one of the standard tricks they teach you in pre-algebra: it's called "completing the square".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$y^2 + y = x  => (y + 1/2)^2 - 1/4 = x =>  (y+  1/2)^2 = x + 1/4 $

Then $(y + 1/2) = \pm \sqrt{x+ 1/4}$ which implies $y = \pm \sqrt{x+ 1/4}  - (1/2)$

Comment: The last $+$ should be a $-$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff thank you, i fixed the error

Answer (score 5):

Initial equation:

$y^2+y-x=0$

Applying Quadratic formula in terms of y, $a=1$, $b=1$, $c=-x$:

$y = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$

Comment: It may be helpful to realize that when you apply the quadratic formula, $x$ should be thought of as a constant. The equation $y^2+y-x=0$ is of the form $ay^2 +by+c=0$, by setting $a=1$, $b=1$, and $c=-x$. If this is too complicated, first try solving e.g. $y^2 + y = 3$ and $y^2 + y = 5$. Once you get how to solve these two, you can apply the technique to the general case $y^2 + y = x$.